# How do we enable the use of attributes in Hyperledger v1.0

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

In Hyperledger v0.6 I use the following switch (environment variable) in my docker commmand to enable the use of attributes in the membership service:

```
-e MEMBERSRVC_CA_ACA_ENABLED=true
```

In Hyperledger v1.0, is there a particular switch (environment variable) I need to set?

I am registering a user that supposedly has an attribute but I can't see the attribute in the certificate when I deserialize it.

I think one of these two is my problem but can't figure out which one:

a. I'm not sure if my membership service is configured properly (e.g., I need to use a similar environment variable (MEMBERSRVC_CA_ACA_ENABLED=true).

b. I'm using the Node HFC SDK incorrectly.  According to the documentation, I need to pass the field "attrs" with an array of key/value attributes.  I used the following:

```
attrs: [{ name: "attr1", value: "attr1value" }, { name: "attr2", value: "attr2value" }]
```

Did I define attrs correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Attributes in certificates are not yet supported in Hyperledger Fabric v1.
The membership service process from v0.6 has been replaced with the
Hyperledger Fabric CA (see https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
Transaction certificates (tcerts) with attributes are not in v1.
See https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-3752 for tracking progress on putting attributes in enrollment certificates (ecerts).

Until this is supported, you can make access control decisions in chaincode based on specific identities by checking specific certificates which should have access.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I would like to clarify what you mean by "specific identities by checking specific certificates"?  Do you mean my access control for now will be based on the user ID / organization?  I am able to get the user ID / organization from the certificates.  If I need an access control based on roles, this is not yet possible for Hyperledger v1?